# Create a clickable list in HTML using JSON data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm using Jquery mobile, and I want to create a clickable view list in my panel. to look something like this...

```
   <li><a href='#' onclick='getmoviepic_mobile(this) ;' > MovieTitle"</a> 
   </li>
```

MovieTitle is obtained from my MYSQL database array using json_encode($x) so when the user clicks on the title the function getmoviepic_mobile(this) is triggered.

My question is how to set up my javascript with json data to populate my html
page.

My HTML

```
<div data-role="panel"  id="Panelcategory" > 

      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="MovieTitle">
          <li></li>        
      </ul> 


 </div >
```

PHP  getcatagories2_mobile.php

```
<?php
include("includes/connection.php");

$q=$_POST['input'];

$resultActor = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,title, 
 plot,catagory,release_date,rated FROM ".TBL_DATA." WHERE catagory LIKE 
'%".$q."%' ORDER BY title  ");  




    while($rowMovie = mysqli_fetch_array($resultActor)) {



    $x[]=$rowMovie['title'];

    }

        $jsonarray=json_encode($x);
        echo $jsonarray;
?>
```

Javascript

```
     function getcatagories(catagory){

        var catagoryValue = $(catagory).text();

       $.getJSON( "getcatagories2_mobile.php", {input:catagoryValue}, 

                function(json) {   this is the part I am stuck on

                               }
```

not sure even if my HTML is set up correctly maybe don't need the "li".

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the JSON and add attributes by key. For example, you could query the list and add each value.

```
$("#MovieTitle").append("<li>" + json["category"] + "</li>")
```

And do so for each key-value pair you want to include.